# Is there a way to Export Firebase Collection to CSV?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to export one of my collections and view it in a CSV file. I have searched the internet but haven't found anything that answers this question.

I have followed the Firebase document, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import, but that just exports it as a metadata file and not a CSV readable file.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method that I know to do it. Your best solution would be to write your own code for that. It would be quite simple. CSV is a very simple format.

There are some exomaples how to expot to json: https://gist.github.com/sturmenta/cbbe898227cb1eaca7f85d0191eaec7e

You could do it with the admin SDK on your own device or using a REST API cloud function. Or even if you want some UI and it's part of your App you can use callable cloud functions. Let me know what would fit your need the best and I could provide some snippets if you want.

I use the lcoal Admin SDK to import and export CSV files from a very old Application into one of my Apps.